# Analytics for PC games: is there anything similar to localytics, flurry, etc?

Tags: pc, analytics

I would like to know if there exists any service such as [Localytics](http://www.localytics.com/) or [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/product/analytics/index.html) but for PC? These ones are mobile focused. It would be really great if they had support for PC too.

In the case there's nothing similar at all, what alternatives or which methods would you recommend for me to keep track of this analytics?

I'm planning to use it in a game and not only to gather generic data such as gender, age, country, etc. What I'd really like is to be able to track gameplay statistics such as: is my game too difficult? (number of deaths per player per level), is my game fun? (number of players who never finish the game and at which point did they stop playing), etc.

Comment: +1 Thanks for sharing. Great question. I didn't know about Flurry. I'm going to integrate it into my app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get this with [Steamworks](https://partner.steamgames.com/). It has an API for putting in gameplay stats-tracking, so you can record things like deaths per location, how many players get to which levels, how long someone plays before quitting, and so on. You can look at the aggregated statistics from all players to get the data you want.

We sometimes use that data for Bayesian inference like "how many deaths does someone typically experience before they have a 50% chance of quitting the game forever" or "how does the frequency of item drops correlate to how often someone logs in to play multiplayer per week."

Note however that getting access to Steamworks [requires your game to be accepted via Steam Greenlight first](http://www.steampowered.com/steamworks/FAQ.php).

Comment: Does it work with XNA/C#?

Comment: @ashes999 Yes, but you would need to write some bindings to wrap the C++ API in a .DLL for your C# to import. Some developers have done that.

Comment: You should add to this answer that to get access to Steamworks requires to be Greenlighted first.

Comment: @Klaim You just did! =)

Comment: @Crashworks I suspect most people to not read the comments, so I submitted an edit which add a clarification (which will be visible if peer aproved).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to Steamworks as suggested by Crashworks, one alternative is to build you own simple analytics system, as explained in this article: http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2013/02/04/brewing-your-own-game-analytics-service/

Comment: The link seems to be dead.

Answer (score -1):

Check out [Countly](http://www.count.ly) - it has an SDK for Mac OS X and an SDK for C# is underway.